# ggplot2 - Discrete value to continuous scale error when making grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to use ggplot2 package to create a grouped bar chart for some chemical data. Here is an example of the data:

```
Well Timepoint Nitrate_avg Nitrate_stdev
1  FW231         0   16.384000     3.9628882
2  FW231         7    0.822000     0.4730544
3  FW231        30    0.000000     0.0000000
4  FW231       150    0.000000     0.0000000
5   GP02         0   12.927306     1.7843047
6   GP02         7    1.776066     0.5034165
7   GP02        30    0.000000     0.0000000
8   GP02       150    0.000000     0.0000000
9   GP01         0   12.822762     3.4921348
10  GP01         7    0.000000     0.0000000
11  GP01        30    0.000000     0.0000000
12  GP01       150    0.000000     0.0000000
13  GP03         0   10.384000     0.2665536
14  GP03         7    0.000000     0.0000000
15  GP03        30    0.000000     0.0000000
16  GP03       150    0.000000     0.0000000
```

I'd like to make a chart that groups Wells together by Time point. However, when trying to do this I keep getting the error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" and I'm not sure why. Here is the code I am using.

```
ggplot(data = cosm_geochem, aes(x = Well, y = Nitrate_avg)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(Timepoint))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Well) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("0", "7", "30", "150"),
                      labels = c("Day 0", "Day 7", "Day 30",
                                 "Day 150"),
                      values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                                 "#F0E442")) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("0", "7", "30", "150"),
                    labels = c("Day 0", "Day 7", "Day 30",
                               "Day 150"),
                    values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                               "#F0E442"))
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I am trying to have each well on the x-axis and a different bar (with unique color) for each time point. Is there a better way to go around this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = Well)`? Seems like `Well` isn't continuous but you are trying to apply a continuous scale. What if you just heave that out?

Comment: I have tried both completely removing     scale_x_continuous and changing it to    scale_x_discrete and I get the error: "Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic." for both.

Comment: I think you want to use `stat="identity",  position="dodge"` and remove `scale_x_continuous`. Something like:`geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(Timepoint)), stat="identity",  position="dodge")`

Comment: Leave out the `scale_x_continuous` and use `geom_col()` rather than `geom_bar()`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much.